# Prometheus does not start with WAL segment loaded

Tags: prometheus

There is a Prometheus installed in Kubernetes Azure AKS with default storage StandardSSD.
Prometheus version v2.47.0

The volume storage size is 1 Gb. Data retention is configured for 1 hour.

Maximum size of data on the volume is about 500Mb.

Prometheus does not start.

It looks like container is being restarted by Kubernetes because Prometheus does not come to live.

Is there a way to do NOT load WAL? Just clean the data and start the sever?

Prometheus log

```
ts=2023-09-26T12:18:22.504Z caller=main.go:583 level=info msg="Starting Prometheus Server" mode=server version="(version=2.47.0, branch=HEAD, revision=efa34a5840661c29c2e362efa76bc3a70dccb335)"
ts=2023-09-26T12:18:22.504Z caller=main.go:588 level=info build_context="(go=go1.21.0, platform=linux/amd64, user=root@409eb5e6b30c, date=20230906-10:20:07, tags=netgo,builtinassets,stringlabels)"
ts=2023-09-26T12:18:22.504Z caller=main.go:589 level=info host_details="(Linux 6.2.0-1012-azure #12~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep  7 14:07:14 UTC 2023 x86_64 prometheus-server-c6dc89b74-sm4qn (none))"
ts=2023-09-26T12:18:22.505Z caller=main.go:590 level=info fd_limits="(soft=1048576, hard=1048576)"
ts=2023-09-26T12:18:22.505Z caller=main.go:591 level=info vm_limits="(soft=unlimited, hard=unlimited)"
ts=2023-09-26T12:18:22.507Z caller=web.go:566 level=info component=web msg="Start listening for connections" address=0.0.0.0:9090
ts=2023-09-26T12:18:22.508Z caller=main.go:1024 level=info msg="Starting TSDB ..."
ts=2023-09-26T12:18:22.508Z caller=repair.go:56 level=info component=tsdb msg="Found healthy block" mint=1695074402397 maxt=1695081600000 ulid=01HANF73XBWEF5B6WXZ81FHC74
ts=2023-09-26T12:18:22.509Z caller=tls_config.go:274 level=info component=web msg="Listening on" address=[::]:9090
ts=2023-09-26T12:18:22.509Z caller=tls_config.go:277 level=info component=web msg="TLS is disabled." http2=false address=[::]:9090
ts=2023-09-26T12:18:22.542Z caller=dir_locker.go:77 level=warn component=tsdb msg="A lockfile from a previous execution already existed. It was replaced" file=/data/lock
ts=2023-09-26T12:18:22.597Z caller=head.go:600 level=info component=tsdb msg="Replaying on-disk memory mappable chunks if any"
ts=2023-09-26T12:18:22.755Z caller=head.go:681 level=info component=tsdb msg="On-disk memory mappable chunks replay completed" duration=157.95156ms
ts=2023-09-26T12:18:22.755Z caller=head.go:689 level=info component=tsdb msg="Replaying WAL, this may take a while"
ts=2023-09-26T12:18:25.156Z caller=head.go:725 level=info component=tsdb msg="WAL checkpoint loaded"
ts=2023-09-26T12:08:41.845Z caller=head.go:760 level=info component=tsdb msg="WAL segment loaded" segment=99 maxSegment=1752
ts=2023-09-26T12:08:41.845Z caller=head.go:760 level=info component=tsdb msg="WAL segment loaded" segment=100 maxSegment=1752
ts=2023-09-26T12:08:41.846Z caller=head.go:760 level=info component=tsdb msg="WAL segment loaded" segment=101 maxSegment=1752
ts=2023-09-26T12:08:41.846Z caller=head.go:760 level=info component=tsdb msg="WAL segment loaded" segment=102 maxSegment=1752
ts=2023-09-26T12:08:41.848Z caller=head.go:760 level=info component=tsdb msg="WAL segment loaded" segment=103 maxSegment=1752
ts=2023-09-26T12:08:41.848Z caller=head.go:760 level=info component=tsdb msg="WAL segment loaded" segment=104 maxSegment=1752
ts=2023-09-26T12:08:41.848Z caller=head.go:760 level=info component=tsdb msg="WAL segment loaded" segment=105 maxSegment=1752
ts=2023-09-26T12:08:41.852Z caller=head.go:760 level=info component=tsdb msg="WAL segment loaded" segment=106 maxSegment=1752
ts=2023-09-26T12:08:41.853Z caller=head.go:760 level=info component=tsdb msg="WAL segment loaded" segment=107 maxSegment=1752
ts=2023-09-26T12:08:41.854Z caller=head.go:760 level=info component=tsdb msg="WAL segment loaded" segment=108 maxSegment=1752
ts=2023-09-26T12:08:41.854Z caller=head.go:760 level=info component=tsdb msg="WAL segment loaded" segment=109 maxSegment=1752
ts=2023-09-26T12:08:41.856Z caller=head.go:760 level=info component=tsdb msg="WAL segment loaded" segment=110 maxSegment=1752
ts=2023-09-26T12:08:41.856Z caller=head.go:760 level=info component=tsdb msg="WAL segment loaded" segment=111 maxSegment=1752
ts=2023-09-26T12:08:41.856Z caller=head.go:760 level=info component=tsdb msg="WAL segment loaded" segment=112 maxSegment=1752
ts=2023-09-26T12:08:41.858Z caller=head.go:760 level=info component=tsdb msg="WAL segment loaded" segment=113 maxSegment=1752
ts=2023-09-26T12:08:41.859Z caller=head.go:760 level=info component=tsdb msg="WAL segment loaded" segment=114 maxSegment=1752
```